# HelpFormatter in Click

Tags: python, python-click

I am using [click](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/click) within a local module and I would like to adjust how the help is displayed:

**Currently output with `--help`:**

```
Usage: __main__.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  foo     Foo is a program very nice and pretty...
```

By default the `prog` name is `__main__.py` and the text is trimmed to 78 chars.

I discovered that this can be adjusted using the `HelpFormatter` class. But I don't know how to use it in this context.

**Current Code:**

```
import click

@click.group()
def main(ctx):
   pass

@main.command()
def foo():
   pass

click.CommandCollection(sources=[main])()
```

**Expected output:**

```
Usage: my_module_name [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  foo     Foo is a program very nice and pretty and this sentence is very long.
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are after, both code and what you are hoping the help will look like?

Comment: I added the expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to to avoid the truncation of the help string, this can be accomplished via the `short_help` parameter.  `short_help` is generally derived from `help` but truncated.  If passed explicitly, the entire string will be displayed.

To display the string `my_module_name`, that can be passed under the parameter `prog_name`

**Test Code:**

```
import click

@click.group()
def main(ctx):
   pass

@main.command(short_help='Foo is a program very nice and pretty and '
                         'this sentence is very long.')
def foo():
   pass

main(['--help'], prog_name='my_module_name')
```

**Results of `short_help`:**

```
Usage: my_module_name [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  foo  Foo is a program very nice and pretty and this sentence is very long.
```

Comment: What about my ´__main__.py' ?

Comment: Do you get that behavior with the test code I just posted? Because I do not see that.

Comment: As long as I put your code in the file `test.py` yes. But if you put it into the file `foo/__main__.py` and you do `PYTHONPATH=. python -m foo --help` you will see `__main__.py` instead of `test.py`...

Comment: Oh, `__main__` is the actual name of your file?  So in that case `__main__.py` is the name of your module.  So you want to be able to specify an arbitrary string there?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would like to specify an arbitrary  string, or better, the name of my module.